# Changing timestamp output format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a date type column in the format '%m%d%Y %H%M%S'. I would like to convert it to timestamp such that the output format matches the format specified above.

However, pd.to_datetime converts this into '%Y%m%d %H%M%S'. How can I convert this back to the previous format?

Comment: Can you add sample - 3-4 rows ? Do you want datetimes in format `%Y%m%d %H%M%S` (it is impossible in python) or datetime saved as string by `df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d %H%M%S')`?

Answer (score 0):

In `python` (`pandas`) is impossible custom format of datetimes, default format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. So if need it, use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for convert to custom `strings`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['02102017 040010','12212017 040010']})

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m%d%Y %H%M%S')
df['orig'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d %H%M%S')
print (df)

              date            datetime             orig
0  02102017 040010 2017-02-10 04:00:10  20170210 040010
1  12212017 040010 2017-12-21 04:00:10  20171221 040010
```

---

```
print (df.dtypes)

date                object
datetime    datetime64[ns]
orig                object
dtype: object

print (df.applymap(type))

            date                                datetime           orig
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>  <class 'str'>
1  <class 'str'>  <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>  <class 'str'>
```

Comment: Downvoter, what is wrong with my answer? I would like to correct it. Thanks.

Comment: I've already considered this approach. However, strftime converts the DateTimeIndex type back to string, which is NOT the objective here. The objective is to merely mutate the display format while detaining the data type. Any thoughts?

P.S - I didn't downvote you. Just saying. Someone downvoted my question as well.

Comment: It is impossible, unfortunately. But I am curious, why do you need it? What is reason? Some plot?